# Query collection containing BsonArray

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Sorry, first time trying mongo.

Given the following data ...

```
db.masterList.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59d128805b19310ac8ab3fc2"),
        "MasterDefinition" : {
                "Location" : [
                        "Whole House",
                        "Master Bedroom",
                        "Hallway 2"
                ],
                "DeviceType" : [
                        "Receptacle",
                        "GFI",
                        "LED dimmer"
                ],
                "Style" : [
                        "Decora",
                        "Standard"
                ],
                "Color" : [
                        "White",
                        "Light Almond"
                ]
        }
}
```

How do I retrieve the contents of the `Color` array? I expect something like

```
["White","Light Almond"]
```

How do I list the 4 arrays directly subordinate to `MasterDefintion`? I expect to see

```
["Location","DeviceType","Style","Color"]
```

Thanks

Comment: "Given the following collection ..." did you intend to add some collection details to your question?

Comment: Could you update your question with (a) what you have tried so far and (b) your **expected** output. Given a clear statement of the output you are looking for, there'll likely be a simple and quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you can simply do a

```
collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "_id": 0, // exclude the "_id" field from the result
        "result": "$MasterDefinition.Color"
    }
})
```

The second part requires a little magic (documentation can be found here: [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/), [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html), [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html)):

```
collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "temp": {
            $objectToArray: "$MasterDefinition" // transform the "MasterDefinition" subdocument into an array
        }
    }
}, {
    $project:{
        "_id": 0, // do not include the "_id" field in the result - this is an optional step
        "result": "$temp.k" // only get the keys (as in "k" fiels) from the array
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I retrieve the contents of the Color array? I expect something like ["White","Light Almond"]

```
// the first argument here is a filter, the second argument is a projection
// since you specified no filter I have only included a projection
// this projection tells MongoDB to return the Color subdocument 
// from within the MasterDefinition sub document
db.getCollection('masterList').find({}, {'MasterDefinition.Color': 1})
```

The above command will return:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d128805b19310ac8ab3fc2"),
    "MasterDefinition" : {
        "Color" : [ 
            "White", 
            "Light Almond"
        ]
    }
}
```

> How do I list the 4 arrays directly subordinate to MasterDefintion? I expect to see ["Location","DeviceType","Style","Color"]

This is a bit trickier because "Location","DeviceType","Style","Color" are not elements in an array instead they are the names of attributes in the `MasterDefinition` subdocument. You can use the [`$objectToArray` aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/#examples) to turn these attribute names into an array but the resulting document doesn't looks exactly like what you hoped for. Here's an example ...

```
db.getCollection('masterList').aggregate([

    // creates an array named "categories" from the attributes of the MasterDefinition sub document
    { $project: { categories: { $objectToArray: "$MasterDefinition" } } }, 

    // projects on the keys of the "categories" array
    {$project: {'categories.k': 1}}

])
```

... which produces this output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d128805b19310ac8ab3fc2"),
    "categories" : [ 
        {
            "k" : "Location"
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "DeviceType"
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "Style"
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "Color"
        }
    ]
}
```